# wxWidgets trouble when trying to use EnableCheckBoxes() maybe CMake mistake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm getting some troubles while trying wxListCtrl::EnableCheckBoxes.

When compiling I get : `class wxListCtrl has no member named 'EnableCheck Boxes`

It should works, because like said on the [official wiki](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac38e3cc09eb86dc6b54560aaa032b73d)
 of wx widgets, it should be available since 3.1.0.

Some possible sources of trouble :

1. There seems to be a typo on the wiki, and it seems to be Enable CheckBoxes ans not EnableCheckboxes (I'm testing both each time)
2. I'm not totally sure my Cmake use the good version of wxwidget (but I don't know how to detect that (`wx-config --version`returns `3.1.0`)
3. In CMakeFile, I've got a `FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets REQUIRED)` (I'm not sure it's finding the good version)
4. I had to build the library myself, and the result *.so are in /usr/local/lib (default location after make install) but I'm not sure if they are in the good place

Before having the need to use EnableCheckB/boxes, I already had a wxwidget, that's why I'm unsure about what version is used by cmake

And last, here is how i'm using it:

```
void f(wxListCtrl* Table)
{
    Table->DeleteAllItems();
    Table->EnableCheckBoxes(); //or Checkboxes, same result
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: [`wxListCtrl`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_list_ctrl.html) doesn't have such function. Did you mean to use [`wxCheckListBox`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_check_list_box.html)?

Comment: Please, have a look here http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ac38e3cc09eb86dc6b54560aaa032b73d
There seems to be a funtion like that

Comment: can we with wxCheckListBox have several columns?

Answer (score 1):

The method was called `EnableCheckboxes()` in 3.1.0, however it was renamed to `EnableCheckBoxes()` later, for consistency with other parts of wx API. So if you really use 3.1.0, you should have the former.

If you're not sure which version you use, you can check this during compile time with `wxCHECK_VERSION(x,y,z)` macro. Or you could also just look at `wx/version.h`.

Comment: Thanks! Now, Iknow that Cmake is using wxwidgt 2.8.12 so I have to find how to make cmake searching for 3.1.0